# Javascript - Fuse.js error - e.split() is not a function

Tags: javascript

Context - I have a requirement to so a fuzzy search and hence I am using fuse.js for my fuzzy search requirement.

I copied the code from fuzzy.min.js from  https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/blob/master/src/fuse.min.js

Error - I am using the same code as given in fusejs.io, yet I am getting the error

> e.split is not a function()

HTML -

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Spark</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="fuse.min.js"></script>

  <script src="gamespic.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

Javascript

```
function search(searchTerm){
  var options = {
    shouldSort: true,
    threshold: 0.6,
    location: 0,
    distance: 100,
    maxPatternLength: 32,
    minMatchCharLength: 1,
    keys: [
      "title"
    ]
  };
  var fuse = new Fuse(myArr, options);
  var result = fuse.search(searchTerm);
  generatePage(result);
}
```

Sample myArr value

```
[
  {
    "api_rate_limit":50000
  },
  {
    "title":"LittleBigPlanet PS Vita",
    "platform":"PlayStation Vita",
    "score":9.0,
    "genre":"Platformer",
    "editors_choice":"Y"
  },
  {
    "title":"LittleBigPlanet PS Vita -- Marvel Super Hero Edition",
    "platform":"PlayStation Vita",
    "score":9.0,
    "genre":"Platformer",
    "editors_choice":"Y"
  },
  {
    "title":"Splice: Tree of Life",
    "platform":"iPad",
    "score":8.5,
    "genre":"Puzzle",
    "editors_choice":"N"
 }]
```

Comment: The first element in your array is missing a `title` property; could that be the issue?

Comment: @gyre I tried by slicing the array but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The variable searchTerm or pattern was not a string but HTML Element object. Since the value was from Textbox, I changed it to searchTerm.value